# terraform - define aws api gateway request parameters from file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameter-passing, terraform, api-gateway

I want to parameterise the request_parameters value in aws-api_gateway_method by using a file

So change:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get" {
  rest_api_id = var.api-id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = "GET"
  request_validator_id = aws_api_gateway_request_validator.validator.id
  request_parameters = { 
    "method.request.querystring.Name" = true 
  }
}
```

into

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get" {
  rest_api_id = var.api-id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = "GET"
  request_validator_id = aws_api_gateway_request_validator.validator.id
  request_parameters = file(var.request-parameters-file)
```

}

I tried that with a .txt file but got an error as the value needs to be a map(bool). Fair enough, but how can I parameterise this field to enable me to use the resource within a module?

I have used a variable of type map(bool) and passed that in which is ok for simple cases but is going to get messy in more complex situations. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent your `request_parameters` as json and then use [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html).

For example:

Have a file `request_parameters.json` with content of:

```
{"method.request.querystring.Name": true }
```

Then in your `aws_api_gateway_method` resource:

```
request_parameters = jsondecode(file("request_parameters.json"))
```